# See all of my activities on Stack Overflow, in chronological order

Tags: support, activity-summary

Is it possible for Stack Overflow users to view all of their activities (questions, comments, etc.) in chronological order? I'd like to see all of the questions I've posted on Stack Overflow, sorted from newest to oldest.

Comment: Just go to your profile and have a look at the activity tab. You can narrow it down to a specific category of activities.

Answer (score 12):

You can get to these screens within a couple of clicks by going to [your user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/975097/anderson-green/), clicking on [`activity`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/975097/anderson-green?tab=activity) and then changing the context to `all`. It should remember that context if you go back there (though I don't know if the mechanism is cookies or something else, so you may need to do so manually if you log in from another computer).

Here is all of your activity, newest to oldest:

- [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/177227/anderson-green?tab=activity&sort=all)
- [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/users/975097/anderson-green?tab=activity&sort=all)
- [system wide (stackexchange.com)](https://stackexchange.com/users/503387/anderson-green?tab=activity)